# EF : Projecting data into a sub-class of a class

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, projection

I'm trying to project some data into a list of POCOs where the POCO contains an instance of another type of POCO.

The two classes are Case and MyEntity, where Case has an instance of MyEntity called Client.

```
public class Case
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CaseReference { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public MyEntity Client { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to query it like this but it's failing reporting "Unable to create a constant value of type MyEntity":

```
 var result = (from c in context.cases
               where c.case_ref.Contains(caseReference)
               select new Case
               {                                      
                   ID = c.id,
                   CaseReference = c.case_ref,
                   Deleted = c.deleted,
                   Client = new MyEntity { ID = c.client.id, Name = c.client.name } 
               }).ToList();
```

What's the best way of doing this, am I going to have to break it down into separate queries?

Comment: i'm wondering if the name 'Entity' is a wise choice when using Entity Framework!! consider a refactor on the name if possible. also, you'd be much better using a dedicated viewmodel for this purpose

Comment: @jim tollan - Thanks, that's a great point, I'd not really given that much thought and will rename it.

Comment: lemme know if this resolves the issue ;)

Comment: It's not resolved it unfortunately, thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Do a `ToList()` after the `select`. EF's IQueryable implementation is more picky about creating new objects in objects than regular linq to objects (IEnumerable).

Comment: @GertArnold - I already have a .ToList(), should I put another one in somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, I meant after the `where`. The point is to make the new objects from an IEnumerable of cases (not IQueryable).

Comment: If I put a .ToList after the where it'll complain that the query body doesn't end in a select clause.

Comment: I always work with fluent syntax. `context.cases.Where(c => c.case_ref.Contains(caseReference).ToList()` ...

Comment: @gertArnold - Thank you! I've managed to re-write the query in fluent syntax and got it working and then translated it back into Query Expression syntax so I could get my head around it. If you post that as an answer I'll happily mark it as the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework's `IQueryable` implementation is more picky about creating new objects in objects than regular linq to objects (`IEnumerable`). If you first convert your query result to `IEnumerable` by ToList():

```
context.cases.Where(c => c.case_ref.Contains(caseReference).ToList()
```

Then you can continue creating `new Case` objects the way you want. (You may need to `Include()` Case.Client in `context.cases`).

Comment: Thanks for your help (and patience!) Gert.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from Gert's answer, I thought I'd post the answer in Query Expression syntax for anyone else having this problem.

Note that I had to add a bit of checking to handle there being no data in the client table:

```
var result = (from c2 in ((from c1 in context.cases
                           where c1.case_ref.Contains(caseReference)
                           select c1).ToList())
              select new Case
              {
                  ID = c2.id,
                  CaseReference = c2.case_ref,
                  Deleted = c2.deleted,
                  Client = (c2.client_id != null ? new MyEntity { ID = c2.client.ID, Name = c2.client.name } : null)
              }).ToList();
```